React: Issue with Skipping Style Update in ShowOn Function
I'm encountering a problem with updating styles in my React application. I have a function ShowOn that should change the width of the TaskTab component and then update the state isActiveShow. However, I've noticed that the code responsible for updating the style is somehow being skipped, and I can't figure out the reason.
Here's my code:
function TaskTab() {
  const [isActiveShow, setIsActiveShow] = useState(false);
  const [taskTabStyle, setTaskTabStyle] = useState({});
  const ShowOn = () => {
    setTaskTabStyle(prevStyle => ({
      ...prevStyle,
      width: prevStyle.width === '279px' ? '' : 'calc(100% - 100px)',
    }));
    setIsActiveShow(!isActiveShow);
  };
  
  const btnShowOffTask = () => {
    setTaskTabStyle(prevStyle => ({
      ...prevStyle,
      width: prevStyle.width === '279px' ? '' : '279px',
    }));
    setIsActiveShow(!isActiveShow);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="row" >
      <div className="col-12">
        <div className="mainScreen"></div>
        <div className="TaskTab" style={taskTabStyle}>
          <button onClick={toggleVisibility} className="btnAddTask">+</button>
          {isActive.map((element, index) => (
            <div key={index} >
              {element}
            </div>
          ))}
          <div className="boxBtnShowOn">
                {isActiveShow ? (<button onClick={btnShowOffTask} className="btnShowOffTask"></button>) : (<button onClick={ShowOn} className="btnShowOn"></button>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TaskTab;

I've ensured that the condition prevStyle.width === '279px' is met and that setTaskTabStyle correctly updates the state. However, when executing the code, the part responsible for updating the style gets skipped.
I'm unable to understand why this is happening and would appreciate any help in identifying the cause of the problem.
Thank you for your attention!
const ShowOn = () => {
  setTaskTabStyle(prevStyle => ({
    ...prevStyle,
    width: prevStyle.width === '279px' ? '' : 'calc(100% - 100px)',
  }));
  setIsActiveShow(!isActiveShow);
};

I've already checked that the condition prevStyle.width === '279px' is met and that setTaskTabStyle correctly updates the state. I've also tried logging various values and checking for any errors in the console, but couldn't find any clues. I was expecting the TaskTab component to update its width according to the condition in the ShowOn function, but for some reason, the code responsible for updating the style seems to be skipped.

Why do you think the code is "being skipped", did you try adding a console.log after the setTaskTabStyle?  Also - I don't fully understand your usecase, but from what I can see you likely chose a very complicated way to achieve a seemingly simple task. Can't you just use a simple state variable with the actual size and then set the style inline in the JSX, somehow like style={{width: isActive ? '279px' : 'calc(..)'}}?

And then simply toggle the boolean in your click handler? This would make the whole code much easier and get rid of one state variable.

    <div className="TaskTab" style={taskTabStyle}>
  {/* ... rest of your content */}
</div>

// Maybe the TaskTab was conditionally rendered before
// if (someCondition) {
//   return (
//     <div className="row">
//       {/* ... */}
//     </div>
//   );
// }

// Now render it always but adjust styles based on state
return (
  <div className="row">
    {/* ... */}
    <div className="TaskTab" style={taskTabStyle}>
      {/* ... rest of your content */}
    </div>
  </div>
);


Thank you for your suggestion! I tried changing the rendering logic of TaskTab as you proposed, but unfortunately, it didn't resolve the issue with skipping style updates.
There might be other problems or oversights in my code that could lead to this issue. I would appreciate further suggestions or assistance in identifying the root cause of the problem.

`const taskTabs = /* ... your logic to get task tabs */;
return (

    {/* ... */}
    {taskTabs.map((taskTab) => (
      
        {/* ... your content */}
      
    ))}
  
);
// Before rendering, check and potentially log the style object:
console.log("taskTabStyle:", taskTabStyle);`

Thank you for your attention to my question! I've identified an issue in my code, which was due to incorrect logic in the ShowOn function. Initially, I was checking the width prevStyle.width against '279px', which hindered the proper updating of styles upon subsequent function calls. After carefully analyzing the code, I made corrections by comparing the width to an empty string ''. I appreciate your attention and support in resolving this issue!

I'm glad to hear that you were able to identify and resolve the issue in your code! If you'd like to replay this conversation or refer back to it later, you can simply bookmark this page or save the conversation transcript for future reference. Additionally, you can always reach out again if you have any more questions or need further assistance.
